# Setting the default value of an input field after data is retrieved causes the content to overlap and the "onChange" event not to be triggered

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, materialize, redux-thunk

I have an "edit category" component in my React application.
The ID is passed through the URL.
When the component is mounted, the action "fetchCategory" is called, which updates the props on the component with the current category.

I have a form which I want to be pre-populated, which I'm currently doing using the defaultValue on the input.

However, this isn't reflected on the state and the label for the text field overlaps the input field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll leave snippets of my code below which could help with understanding what I'm trying to do.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchCategory } from "../../store/actions/categoryActions";

class AddOrEditCategory extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCategory(this.props.match.params.id);

    if (this.props.match.params.id) {
      this.setState({
        _id: this.props.match.params.id
      });
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  render() {
    const addingNew = this.props.match.params.id === undefined;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h4>{addingNew ? "Add category" : "Edit category"}</h4>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name"
              defaultValue={this.props.category.name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="name">Category name</label>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="urlKey"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              defaultValue={this.props.category.urlKey}
            />
            <label htmlFor="urlKey">URL Key</label>
          </div>
          <button className="btn">{addingNew ? "Add" : "Save"}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    category: state.categoryReducer.category
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchCategory }
)(AddOrEditCategory);
```

EDIT: Included whole component as requested

Comment: In your handleChange you are setting e.target.id which is "name".
That does not exist in your state. What are you trying to set in that function. Need more context

Comment: The handleChange function is applied to all text fields. Therefore, when the text changes, it updates the state to add the key as the input field's id and the value to the value of the input field

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question to include the whole component.

Comment: Added answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the 'defaultValue' attribute with 'value' in the inputs.

You are using a controlled vs uncontrolled component. You dont need to use defaultValue.

You can set the initial values on the promise success for fetchCategory

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchCategory(this.props.match.params.id).then(response => { 
    // Set the initial state here 
  }
}
```

OR in

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // Compare current props with next props to see if there is a change
  // in category data received from action fetchCategory and set the initial state 
}
```

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

```
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div className="input-field">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.name} //<---
        />
        <label htmlFor="name">Category name</label>
      </div>
      <div className="input-field">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="urlKey"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.urlKey}
        />
        <label htmlFor="urlKey">URL Key</label>
      </div>
      <button className="btn">{addingNew ? "Add" : "Save"}</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When calling this.props.fetchCategory("XXXX") inside componentDidMount, the props are automatically mapped to the component using Redux so it seems redundant to copy those values straight to the state.

Also, after following your suggestions, when the value is changed (after Thunk has finished populating the props again after fetchCategory is completed), I get this error: "Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled."

Comment: Yes, but your inputs need to change and rely on the state. So if you want to set defaults, the props will need to be mapped to the local state (which in turn updates ur input values).

Regarding the warning:- You need to set default values for the input related states otherwise the value attribute will be undefined till the action is complete, which results in that  warning

Comment: Perfect, all working. Thanks so much. I'm still learning so I'm sorry if I'm coming across stupid. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No worries. These are very common issues/hurdles encountered when you start React.
Good luck!